# Why does $e^x$ have no solution?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analysis

Since $e^x$ can be represented by an infinitely long Taylor polynomial, and by the fundamental theory of algebra every degree-$n$ polynomial has $n$ roots, why doesn't $e^x$ have infinitely (or any) real or complex solution?

Comment: It's not a polynomial,  so theorems about polynomials aren't obviously relevant.

Comment: An "infinitely long polynomial" (more commonly called a "power series") is not a polynomial, so the fundamental theorem of algebra doesn't apply

Comment: @Skully For a function $f(x)$, solutions to the equation $f(x) = 0$ are called "roots of $f$" or "zeros of $f$", but not "solutions of $f$".

Comment: Incidentally, it's a good exercise to pick a proof of the fundamental theorem of algebra and see exactly where it breaks down if we try to apply it to power series instead of genuine (finite) polynomials. For example, in the Liouville's-theorem-based proof that I first learned, we rely on the polynomial having a leading term in order to bound its reciprocal's magnitude outside a compact region. Power series don't have highest-degree terms!

Comment: @Skully You mean find the [Picard theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_theorem) to be interesting. These tell you about the zeros of functions that can be written in the form of a power series (at least, they can be written in the form of a power series over certain regions of convergence for those series).

Comment: This is a good question! Keep thinking about these things.

Comment: Actually polynomials have roots only over algebraically closed fields. In particular the theorem does not apply to $\mathbb{R}$. Secondly, congratulations, you just found a big difference between polynomials and "infinitely long polynomials", or what we would call: series. These are not the same, their properties do not coincide.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2895800/42969 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1631886/42969.

Comment: Indeed assuming $e^x=0$ true for some $x\in \mathbb R$ implies $e^x=0$ for any $x$.

Comment: $|e^z|=|e^{x+iy}|=|e^xe^{iy}|=|e^x||e^{iy}|=|e^x|>0$.

Answer (score 1):

First, the commentaors are completely right in saying that a series wih infinitely many terms is not a polynomial, so theorems about polynomials are irrelevant. Second, your staement about "$e^x$ have no soluiton" is completely meaningless. Functions do not have solutions. Equations may or may not have solutions. You probably mean to ask about possible solutions o the equation $e^x=0$. Third suppose there is some $x$ such that $e^x=0$. Then $e^x e^{-x}=0e^{-x}=0$ but $e^xe^{-x}=e^{-x+x}=e^0=1$, a contradiction.

Comment: I think point 2 is making too much of a simple terminological error. OP may be trying to translate from their native language. Ben Grossman's approach in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4715136/why-does-ex-have-no-solution#comment9986365_4715136 seems to me to be more to the point.

Comment: So, we can make this into an elementary problem:  if a function $F : \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ satisfies $F(x+y)=F(x)F(y)$ for all $x,y$, then either $F$ is identically zero or $F$ is never zero.

Comment: @MJD I can not understand the answer . By definition $a^{-m}=\frac 1{a^m}$ so $e^{-x}=\frac 1{e^x}.$ Therefore, if $e^x=0$, then $e^{-x}$ is simply undefined. This turns to a circular logic : $0\cdot \frac 10=1$ A contradiction ? I would think this is not a contradiction. This operation is just undefined , I think .

Comment: @lonestudent: No, $e^{-x}=\frac 1{e^x}$ is not “by definition.” $e^x$ is defined as an infinite  series (for all real or complex $x$), and so is $e^{-x}$. Then $e^x \cdot e^{-x} = 1$ can be *proven* using that definition, and it follows that no factor in that product can be zero. – But actually all this has been said before, the question is a duplicate IMO.

Comment: @MartinR  Thanks, but my highschool textbook says $a^{-m}=\frac 1{a^m}$ is definition of $a^{-m}$ . Now, I am confusing .

Comment: @lonestudent:  Well, there are many different approaches to define $a^x$ for a general exponent $x$. One way is to define it for positive integer exponents first, then for arbitrary integer exponents, then for rational exponents, and finally for real exponents. – There are also different ways to define the Euler number, e.g. as $\sum_{n=0}^\infty 1/n!$ or as $\lim_{n\to \infty} (1+1/n)^n$.

Comment: (Cont.) I am referring to the definition of the exponential function as $\exp(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n/n!$, which can be shown to satisfy $\exp(x+y) = \exp(x) \cdot \exp(y)$ (and also $a^x = \exp(x \ln(x))$, which in turn can be used as the *definition* of $a^x$). – So it really depends on what you define in which order.

Comment: @MartinR Thank you for your comments. I guess I understand your comments.  If this were a high school-level exam question (with real exponent ), I would answer it like this : Obviously $x≠0$ . Then  if $e^x=0$ then $e^{2x}=0^2=0$. This implies $e^x=e^{2x}$ . This folllows $x=2x\implies x=0 .$ A Contr.

Comment: @lonestudent I'm not sure I follow your proof. Why is it obvious that $x \neq 0$ in the beginning?

Comment: @lonestudent ...or that $e^x=0$ for any $x\neq 0$

Comment: @Accelerator Because $a^0=1$  by definition of $a^{-m}=\frac {1}{a^m}.$  So $a^0=\frac {1}{a^0}\implies \left(a^0\right)^2=1\implies a^0=1$ .

Comment: @user yes, indeed .

Comment: @lonestudent I'm sorry, but I still don't follow. I don't know where $a$ came from, and it seems like you tried to prove that $a^0 = 1$ by supposing $a^0 = 1$ by definition?

Comment: @lonestudent I think it's better for you to forget about the $a$ thing because it's confusing. When you want to prove that $e^x \neq 0$ for any real (or even complex) $x$, you can't assume what you want to prove. It's like asking a friend to prove they can run faster than you because you're curious who's faster, but that friend just answers, "I can clearly run faster." I'm sure you would ask, "How? You didn't do anything." If knowing what to suppose and what to prove confuses you, you can try reading an introductory proofs textbook to understand.